# Non-abelian groups of order less than or equal to 150

Tags: finite-groups, noncommutative-algebra, gap

Please is there anywhere one could see a classification of nonabelian groups of orders less than or equal to 150?

Comment: Should we add the (long-list) or the (reference-request) tag?

Comment: Long list is ok. Actually, I will appreciate how to derive them or possibly the forms of the groups...especially the ones of even orders. tnx

Comment: It's going to be pretty terrible. There are [over two thousand groups](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_128) of order $2^7$ alone, only $15$ abelian.

Comment: There are $2328$ groups (up to isomorphism) of order $128$ of which just fifteen are abelian. Most orders will have a small number of such groups, but the number of groups for powers of two increases rapidly.

Comment: If you are interested in theoretical approaches to the classification, start from papers by [Bettina Eick](http://www.icm.tu-bs.de/~beick/pl.html) where you will also find references to earlier classifications for certain orders. I can't tell without looking up there, what's the minimal order that has been enumerated only using computers, though.

Comment: Also, it's interesting where the bound of 150 comes from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could download GAP or Sage or acquire a copy of Magma. In GAP there's a function called $$\text{"AllSmallGroups($N$)"}$$ which gives you a list of all the groups of order $N$ up to isomorphism. For each one you can then use "StructureDescription(G)" for GAP to give you a short description of the group in terms of common names of groups, (semi)direct products, (non)split extensions, etc. Sage uses GAP, so it will have similar functions (with possibly different names/syntax). Magma also has this function.

By the way, there are LOTS of nonabelian groups of order $\le 150$, and most of them won't have an easy description. The description given by "StructureDescription" is also not even an isomorphism invariant - Two isomorphic groups could have different "StructureDescriptions" (for example $D_6 = \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, and two nonisomorphic groups may have the same StructureDescription. For example, even describing a simple semidirect product requires not only the two groups involved, but also a homomorphism from one into the automorphism group of the other. That's a significant amount of information - even if you only list where the homomorphism sends the generators, you still need to set up notation for how you will refer to those generators. The purpose of StructureDescription is only to give you a quick, short, and rough understanding of the group.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful hint.

Comment: (+1) Very good points about `StructureDescription`! See also [Can non-isomorphic groups have equal structure descriptions?](http://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#7.12) and links to corresponding GAP manual sections.